# Failure to "opam init", how to manually specify index.tar.gz?

Tags: ocaml, opam

I cannot `opam init`:

```
$ opam init --verbose
[NOTE] Will configure from built-in defaults.
Checking for available remotes: rsync and local, git, mercurial.
  - you won't be able to use darcs repositories unless you install the darcs command on your system.


<><> Fetching repository information ><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
[ERROR] Could not update repository "default": OpamDownload.Download_fail(_, "Curl failed: \"/usr/bin/curl --write-out %{http_code}\\\\n --retry 3 --retry-delay 2
        --user-agent opam/2.0.7 -L -o /tmp/opam-1697-6d07ae/index.tar.gz.part https://opam.ocaml.org/index.tar.gz\" exited with code 28")
[ERROR] Initial download of repository failed
```

However, I've manually downloaded `index.tar.gz`. How to manually specify `index.tar.gz` to `opam init`?

System info:

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-10.0-19043 xxx 3.4.5-1.x86_64 2023-01-19 19:09 UTC x86_64 Cygwin
```

P.S. I'm trying to build one project using OCaml, but it turned out that it is *very tricky*: either OCaml complains about compatibility (`is not a compiled interface for this version of OCaml` followed by `It seems to be for an older version of OCaml`; does it mean that OCaml is not backward compatible?), either `opam init` fails, either `<whatever>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message indicates that you either have network problems or very poor connection. Also, you opam version is very old, so it might not handle bad networks very well, I would suggest your installing a newer version of opam (at least 2.1.x), or, if it is possible, switching to docker or a virtual machine.

Answering your original question: I don't think there is a way (at least officially supported to specify your own downloaded index). Also, if you have trouble with downloading the index it most likely means that you will have more trouble in the future with your network when opam will start downloading actual packages.